# New pc not booting with 2 RAM sticks (only works with one)

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

New setup: i7 6700K, mobo Asus B150M-C and 2 sticks of Kingston 16GB DDR4 2133.
That mobo handles up to 64GB DDR4 2133 and has 4 slots. So everything should work. Well, it works only using one of the sticks (doesn't matter which one). If I try putting both sticks (in the order that the manual says) it does not boot (I can't access to Bios)

Possible solutions anyone? I want to use all 32gb!

Ps.: the Bios is updated.

Comment: Did you reset the CMOS using the jumper too?

Comment: Is there any POST message or will it just shut down again w/o showing anything?

Comment: If it's a new rig, return the motherboard and get something overclockable (Z series chipset). Buying "K" CPUs and not overclocking is a waste of money.

Answer (score 3):

Oh god. Solved. 
Booted it with a single stick > opened Bios > enabled XMP > shut off > installed the other stick and now it just works!

This thing is stupid. Asus, why is this mobo designed to refuse two sticks unless XMP is enabled?

Thank you everyone. Can't explain it myself.

Comment: Curious... there must have been some existing manual speed setting that enabling XMP cleared out, but I don't know what setting would be fine for the modules individually but not work with them in a pair

Answer (score 0):

Use one stick of ram and test each slot on the board. When using only one stick of ram the computer should boot normaly regardles of wich slot used. This method is used to find damaged ramslots. 
If you find a slot that prevents the computer to boot it could be the cpu or the wiring on the board that is damaged. First thing to test is to take out the cpu and check for bent pins in the cpu socket put cpu back and check if computer now boots using the failed ramslot.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems with my second RAM stick for months, until finally my computer wouldn't boot up unless I took the second stick out. I tried every possible solution, and in the end it was something that seems to happen a lot, but isn't very well documented. I'll just give you my experience in case anyone comes here with a search engine: IT WAS A PROBLEM WITH THE CPU.

The computer was less than a year old:
Ryzen 5 5600 with an MPG B550I GAMING EDGE MAX WIFI and corsair Vengance LP 32GB.

It seems that something was wrong with the CPU's B channel. There were no bent pins or any other damage.

I've just bought a cheap used Ryzen 5 1600 to test. Everything immediately worked as it should. I sent the 5600 to RMA. I received a new one in less than 2 weeks and now everything works perfectly.

I hope this helps people like me who couldn't solve the problem with the "normal" solutions!